# Javascript/ajax updating database when value changes

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, database

i need some help in making an ajax code that updates this javascript code into msql database.

```
 switch(direction)
       {
          case 'up':    index = 0;  y =  1;  if(Y++)('update Y+1')   break;
          case 'right': index = 3;  x = -1;  if(X--)('update X-1')  break;
          case 'left':  index = 9;  x =  1;  if(X++)('update X+1')  break;
          case 'down':  index = 6;  y = -1;  if(Y--)('update Y-1')  break;

       }
```

im kinda new in javascript but isnt possible to update the script using setinterval?
like this

```
`case 'up':    index = 0;  y =  1;  if(Y++) {  setInterval(function() {<?php mysql_query=("update that set ....") ?>}, 1000);  } break
```

Really appreciate if anybody can help me doing this.

Comment: Are you using the jquery library ?

Comment: What do you actually want to update?

Comment: Here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started. The corresponding server side code obviously depends on the language you are using.

Comment: im using php programming language,i want to update X,Y valuses in the databasesand i'm not using jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly update the database using ajax. With ajax you can call a server file which will then update the database.

You can use this sample code to move forward with ajax

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
// Write you success code
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","<<Server file which you need to call>>",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I hope this code helps you.

Comment: im still confuse about it,i know i cannot directly update mysql using javascript,at least i want to use ajax to update X,Y values every minute